# Informação Seletiva e Organizada em Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Tenho duas listas que me mandam em tempo real (ou seja, a cada segundo) informações se o jogador está online ou offline.

```
def online(nome):
   # aqui será armazenado o nome da pessoa que está online

def offline(nome):
   # aqui será armazenado a pessoa que está offline
```

Queria que houvesse uma forma de guardar ambos os valores mas mostrar primeiramente os que estão online e só depois os offline:

```
OUTPUT:
Nome A do jogador online
Nome B do jogador online
Nome C do jogador online
Nome A do jogador offline
Nome B do jogador offline
```

Sei que é por **append** caso queira fazer por uma lista e **update** caso queira fazer por um dicionário, mas o problema é que as informações enviam uma em cima da outra e **eu preciso que esteja estudo numa só lista/dicionário/tupla/** o que acharem melhor para o meu problema!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existem algumas opções. Mas, vamos por partes.

## Pensando na estrutura

Existem vários jogadores e eles podem estar online ou offline. Pensando apenas nestas informações a estrutura que vem à cabeça inicialmente é a **lista**, porém lista de que?

### Opção 1

Lista de jogadores online e de usuários offline.

O acesso ao dado é simples utilizando um for, porém caso o usuário mude o status de online para offline ou vice-versa, embora não seja complexo, exige a retirada de uma lista e inclusão em outra

Exemplo:

```
jogadores_online = ["Pedro", "Joao"...]
jogadores_offline = ["Jose", "Maria"...]
```

### Opção 2

Lista de tuplas de jogadores contendo seu status.

Em uma única lista vc possui todos os jogadores, simples de acessar. Porém, sendo
as tuplas imutáveis, em uma mudança de status, teria que retirar o item da lista e reincluir com um novo status.

```
# True para jogador online e False para offline
jogadores = [ ("Pedro", True), ("Joao", True), ("Jose", False), ("Maria", False)]
```

Para acessar esta lista, você pode percorrê-la usando `for` ou usar o `filter`

Exemplo 1: Lista de jogadores

```
nomes_jogadores = []
for j in jogadores:
    nomes_jogadores.append(j[0])
```

ou

```
nomes_jogadores = [j[0] for j in jogadores]
```

Exemplo: Lista de jogadores online

```
nomes_jogadores_online = []
for j in jogadores:
    if j[1]:
        nomes_jogadores_online.append(j[0])

print(nomes_jogadores_online)
['Pedro', 'Joao']
```

ou

```
jogadores_online = filter(lambda j: j[1], jogadores)

print(list(jogadores_online))
[('Pedro', True), ('Joao', True)]
```

**Nota**: o `filter` no Python 3 não retorna uma lista. Ele retorna um iterável e pode ser acessado com `for`.

ou ainda, de forma explícita

```
def is_online(j):
    return j[1]

jogadores_online = filter(is_online, jogadores)

print(list(jogadores_online))
[('Pedro', True), ('Joao', True)]
```

**Nota**: Repare que usando o filter ele retorna a tupla e não somente os nomes. Caso queira apenas os nomes, use o `map` em conjunto com o `filter` conforme abaixo:

```
jogadores_online = map(lambda x: x[0], filter(is_online, jogadores))

print(list(jogadores_online))
['Pedro', 'Joao']
```

**Nota**: O `map` também retorna iterável

### Opção 2.5

Lista de listas de jogadores contendo seu status.

```
# True para jogador online e False para offline
jogadores = [ ["Pedro", True], ["Joao", True], ["Jose", False], ["Maria", False] ]
```

A vantagem frente à Opção 2 é que a lista é mutável, podendo assim trocar o status do jogador

```
# Mudando o status do Pedro
jogadores[0][1] = False
```

### Opção 3

Lista de objetos.

```
class Jogador:
    def __init__(self, nome, status):
        self.nome = nome
        self.status = status

jogadores = []
jogadores.append(Jogador("Joao", True))
jogadores.append(Jogador("Pedro", True))
jogadores.append(Jogador("Jose", False))
jogadores.append(Jogador("Maria", False))
```

Em caso de o jogador precisar de mais atributos é fácil modificar (este seria o contra para opção 2 e 2.5)

As funções de `filter` e `map` podem ser usadas nesta estrutura uma vez que os objetos estão em uma lista

```
jogadores_online = filter(lambda j: j.status, jogadores)
```

### Opção 4

Lista de dicionários

```
jogadores = [{"nome": "Joao", "status": True}, {"nome": "Pedro", "status": True}, {"nome": "Jose", "status": False }, {"nome": "Maria", "status": False}]
```

Em uma estrutura simples, faz sentido. As funções `filter` e `map` podem ser utilizadas

### Opção 5

Fugindo das listas temos o Dicionario

```
jogadores = {
             "Joao": True,
             "Pedro": True,
             "Jose": False,
             "Maria": False
            }
```

Considerando que cada jogador possui um nome único, esta é a solução mais fácil, pois você pode acessar o jogador diretamente pelo nome e verificar seu status. A função `filter` pode ser usada caso você acesse `jogadores.items()`

```
print(jogadores.items())
dict_items([('Joao', True), ('Pedro', True), ('Jose', False), ('Maria', False)])
```

### Opção N

Lista de `namedtuple` (não vou entrar em detalhes) Para maiores informações veja [aqui](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html)

```
from collections import namedtuple
```

Agora a decisão é do implementador

Espero ter ajudado

Comment: Muito obrigado!!

Comment: Bacana demais! +1